# how to Remove array and created new array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

This Is my array:

```
array(10) { 
  [0]=> string(29) "Cass Luxury Shapewear Bottoms"
  [1]=> string(8) "xBhjsN9G"
  [2]=> string(2) "20"
  [3]=> string(57) "Cass Luxury Shapewear Bottoms. Multiple Styles Available."
  [4]=> string(29) "cass-luxury-shapewear-bottoms" 
  [5]=> string(28) "Curabitur non nulla sit amet"
  [6]=> string(8) "vjIhw8cw"
  [7]=> string(3) "500"
  [8]=> string(690) "posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque."
  [9]=> string(28) "curabitur-non-nulla-sit-amet"
}
```

remove this array:

```
[5]=> string(28) "Curabitur non nulla sit amet"
[6]=> string(8) "vjIhw8cw"
[7]=> string(3) "500"
[8]=> string(690) "posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque."
[9]=> string(28) "curabitur-non-nulla-sit-amet"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unset()` to unset an array like this:

```
unset($array[5]);  //if the index is 5
```

As an example:

```
<?php

    $array = array(
                array(1),
                array(2)
            );

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);

    unset($array[1]);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

)


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to looping and delete by its index.

```
// $items is your array variable

for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {

    if ($i >= 5 && $i <= 9) {
        unset($items[$i]);
    }
}

print_r($items);
```

Hope it can help